# Point of confusions for: $H$ and $K$ are unequal subgroups of a group $G$, each of order $16$. Prove that $24 \leq |H \cup K| \leq 31$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For the following question related to lagrange's theorem: suppose that $H$ and $K$ are unequal subgroups of a group $G$, each of order $16$.  Prove that $24 \leq |H \cup K| \leq 31$.

There are some confusions I am hoping someone can clarify for me please.

(1) When it says "unequal subgroups", does it mean $|H\cap K|=\{1\}$?

(2)  Am I correct to assume that $H\cup K$ is a subgroup and hence either $K\subset H$ or $H \subset K$.  Then either $|H|||K|$ or $|K|||H|$

(3)  There is another theorem that states: if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, $<H\cup K>=HK$. I don't think this fact is relevant.

(4) to get $31$ on the right hand side.  We have $|H \cup K|=|H|+|K|-|H\cap K|=16+16-1=31$

(5) for the left lower bound $24$, I am not sure how to get it. Also could it be even lower like to $3$ for $|H|=|K|=2$ and $|H\cap K|=1$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are unequal if $a\neq b$.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: If $H\subset K$ or $K\subset H$ then $H\cup K= K $ or $H\cup K= H$.Hence $|H\cup K|=16$ $\\$ Here we have to consider join of two subgroups i.e subgroup generated by $H\cup K$

Comment: "only have the identity in common" is called "trivial intersection", not "distinct". "Distinct" means "unequal" or "different". It means they are not the exact same subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin unequal here means unequal as sets?

Comment: Note that "$|H\cap K|=\{1\}$" is nonsense. The left hand side is a number or cardinal (the size of the intersection). The right hand side is a set containing the identity element if $G$. It should be either "$H\cap K=\{1\}$" or "$|H\cap K|=1$".

Comment: Unequal means unequal. Not equal. **Of course** as sets, given the context that they are both subgroups of the same group. (so it can't be different group structures on the same underlying set). There really is no other plausible or reasonable interpretation here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for catching that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin can i just ask you one quick question about my post.  The upper and lower bound for $|H \cup K|$ has nothing to do with whether $H \cup K$ ia considered as a group?

Comment: $H\cup K$ is a group if and only if $H\subseteq K$ or $K\subseteq H$; [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1484593/742). Since $|H|=|K|$ is finite, and $H\neq K$,  you cannot have either inclusion, so it is not a question of whether you "consider" it a group. It's **not** a group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah you are right.  I keep forgetting that they have the same cardinality and hence is not allowed for at least one of the inclusions.

Comment: $H\ne K$ means that there is some $h\in H$ and $h\notin K$, or there is some $k\in K$ and $k\notin H$.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo thanks for reminding me of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given that order of $H$ and $K$ both are $16$. Again $H \cap K$ is a subgroup and as it is contained in both $H$ and $K$. So $|H \cap K|$ will divide $|H|$ and as well as $|K|$. So we have choices for order of $H \cap K$ are $1,2,4,8,16$. Now order of $H \cap K$ can't be $16$. Because if it is $16$ then $H \cap K=K$ and also $H \cap K=H$. So we will get that $H=K$, which can't happen. So we have $1 \le |H \cap K| \le 8$. So now using the formula of basic set theory $|H \cup K|=|H|+|K|-|H \cap K|$ we clearly have the result that you have claimed.

Answer (score 1):

Since $H\ne K$, then $1\le\lvert H\cap K\rvert \le8\implies 24\le\lvert H\cup K\rvert \le31$.

(BTW, $H\cup K$ won't be a group.)

Comment: I thought I am to interpret it as a group assuming either $H\subset K$ or $K\subset H$

Comment: Not when they're the same order.   They'd be equal.